# Solving the Line Integral in Ampère's Law mathematical correctly

Tags: electromagnetism, path-integral, magnetostatics

Imagen we have a infinite long, cylindrical conductor with radius $\varrho_0$ and

$\textbf{j}=\begin{cases}j_0 \textbf{e_z} &r\leq \varrho_0\\ 0 &r>\varrho_0\end{cases}$

We have Ampère's Law: 
$$\oint_{\partial F} \textbf{B}\cdot\textbf{dr}=\frac{4\pi}{c}I=\frac{4\pi}{c}\int_F \textbf{j}\cdot\textbf{dF} \tag{1}$$

whereas $F$ is the cross-section area of the conductor.

Now we have to solve that integral on the LHS. We usually do it by using our physics knowledge. In this case, we integrale "along" the same direction as the magnetic field, so on that curve, it's constant. So we get

$$\textbf{B}(\textbf{r})=B(\varrho)\textbf{e}_\varphi \tag{2}$$
$$\textbf{dr}=\varrho\textbf{e}_\varphi d\varphi \tag{3}$$

so we get

$$\oint_{\partial F}\textbf{B}\cdot \textbf{dr}=B(\varrho)\varrho\int_0^{2\pi}d\varphi=\dots \tag{4}$$

Now here starts my confusion. It's clear why we get a constant magnetic field and why we can pull it out. So basically, I'd be able to solve the exercise now but I'm just very unsure what went on (mathematically) in (4).

I think we have a line integral over a vectorfield, so:

Let $\textbf{f}: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ be a continuous vector field.

Let $\boldsymbol{\gamma}: [a,b]\to\mathbb R^n$ be a parameterization of our curve.

We then have

$$\int_\boldsymbol{\gamma} \textbf{f}(\textbf{x})\cdot \textbf{dx}:=\int_a^b \textbf{f}(\boldsymbol{\gamma}(t))\cdot \dot{\boldsymbol{\gamma}}(t)dt \tag{5}$$

Now, we have to think about what $\partial F$ is. It's obviously a circle. So we make the following parameterization:

$$\boldsymbol{\gamma}: [0,2\pi]\to\mathbb R^2, \ t\mapsto \varrho\begin{pmatrix}\cos(t) \\ \sin(t) \end{pmatrix} \tag{6}$$

$$\dot{\boldsymbol{\gamma}}(t)=\varrho\begin{pmatrix}-\sin(t) \\ \cos(t) \end{pmatrix} \tag{7}$$

so we get

$$\int_{\partial F} \textbf{B}\cdot \textbf{dr}=\int_0^{2\pi}\textbf{B}(\boldsymbol{\gamma}(t))\cdot \dot{\boldsymbol{\gamma}}(t)dt \tag{8}$$

of course, we can't really evaluate $\textbf{B}(\boldsymbol{\gamma}(t))$ since we actually want to get $\textbf{b}$. So we start thinking and see:

$$\textbf{B}(\boldsymbol{\gamma}(t))=B(\boldsymbol\varrho )\textbf{e}_\varphi \tag{9}$$
$$\dot{\boldsymbol{\gamma}}(t)=\varrho \begin{pmatrix}-\sin(t) \\ \cos(t) \end{pmatrix} =\varrho\textbf{e}_\varphi \tag{10}$$
so we plug it in (8) and get

$$\int_{\partial F} \textbf{B}\cdot \textbf{dr}=\int_0^{2\pi}\textbf{B}(\boldsymbol{\gamma}(t))\cdot \dot{\boldsymbol{\gamma}}(t)dt=B(\textbf{r})\varrho\int_0^{2\pi} dt = 2\pi B(\boldsymbol \varrho)\varrho \tag{11}$$

So thi seems correct. We aren't finished with calculating the magnetic field but we solved the integral, which was my question. But I'm still unsure if everything really holds well and I'm also unsure about (9). That's just physics and not math but I'm unsure about if it really does depend on $\boldsymbol\varrho$ or $\varrho$ or even $\textbf{r}$ or $r$

Comment: Make note of the formatting I have edited for future reference. Did you want $\gamma$ to be $\boldsymbol\gamma$?

Comment: Thanks @AaronStevens I used the non-bold $\gamma$ cause my [reference](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurvenintegral#Wegintegral_zweiter_Art) did it like that. Thought it seems odd but thought maybe it's a convention for curves or something like that. I'm gonna change it.

Comment: Wow! I learned how to do bold greek symbols in MathJax from reading your post.  I assume that your reference did not use bold only  because bold greek is not included in many fonts.

Comment: @mikestone Yep. Enjoy the new trick!